# And Design Switch Component CSS displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I am building an application where the switch component is displaying like this (with straight edges)

[image: incorrect what the image is displayed]

the code that is being rendered is as follows

```html
<button type="button" role="switch" aria-checked="false" class="ant-switch" style="margin-right: 16px;"><span class="ant-switch-inner"></span></button>
```

However the switch is supposed to look like this (with curved edges)

[image: correct what the image is displayed]

```html
<span class="ant-switch" tabindex="0" style="margin-right: 16px;"><span class="ant-switch-inner"></span></span>
```

I am using the And Design framework and importing it as a standard component. I am not applying any style to it. however something is causing it to be rendered as a button rather than a span.

```html
import { Switch } from "antd";
<Switch/>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? or does any one know how to force a the component to be rendered as the span component rather that a button component?

Comment: are you using AND or ANT design? and how are you importing the css?